# How to allow Laravel admin user to simulate or authenticate as any other user on my site?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to figure out how quickest and easiest to allow the admin user on the site I'm building to access and update any user's settings etc. E.g. I've written the code for a regular user to update their settings (and various other actions). Ideally I want an admin to be able to "be" that user as far as my code is concerned, i.e. allow the admin to do anything a user can, to that user's account. Is there any way of doing this?

If I Auth::login() as admin then from the point of view of Laravel I'm the admin user and not the user they might want to edit. If I login as the user then I don't have admin rights (which in my case means an extra admin menu on the navbar with options to suspend or delete the user, or search for other users).

Any thoughts on how to do this please, or am I overcomplicating things? I am looking for a specific functions/code to allow this, rather than a general strategy. I'm using Laravel 5.4, deployed on Heroku. I know there's middleware but it doesn't seem to do what I want as above.

Many thanks.

Comment: Create a `CRUD` editor for Users: define a route for `/user/{id}/edit`, create a Controller to handle, navigate and edit when logged in as an Admin. That all being said, this requirement: *"[...] looking for a specific functions/code to allow this, rather than a general strategy [...]"* is impossible for us to accommodate, since you didn't post any code for us to work with. Also, this is really broad.

Comment: @TimLewis yes thanks, I've got that for users to be able to edit their settings etc for example, issue is how to handle it when logged in user is the admin, but trying to edit a different user's settings. I don't want to have to duplicate code...

Comment: Then ditch the profile edit (editing self only) and add logic to use `/user/{id}/edit` only; if you're logged in as an Admin, you can edit any `id`, including your own. If you're not logged in as an Admin, you can only access `/user/{own-id}/edit`; that would remove duplicated code. Also, it's ok to duplicate code; profile editing and User editing (to me) is different enough that duplication is ok.

Comment: > "if you're logged in as an Admin, you can edit any id, including your own" - yes that's exactly what I'm trying to work out how to do, i.e. how to tell Laravel to update the selected user's settings rather than the logged in Admin user's settings, for example. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: No problem. The answer below touches on that logic, so definitely check that one out and see what you can implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as suggested in the above comment by Tim Lewis, or you could accept an "override" property in the user edit page where you can pass a specific user ID and then view the page as that user. For instance, the method might look like this:

```
public function editUser(User $user=null) {
    //User that you want to edit can be provided. If not provided, $user will be null and we will load the user that is currently logged in.
    if($user!=null && Auth::user()->role=='admin')
        $user_to_edit = $user;
    else
        $user_to_edit = Auth::user();

    //other code goes here
}
```

Then, if you pass a $user object to the method, you will be given the edit page for that user, rather than the Admin. Otherwise, a user will be able to use the same route in order to always view their own edit page.

Be very careful with code like this! You will want to make sure that non-admins do not have the ability to load in a user object and see somebody else's information. That's why I added the $user->role check in the if/else statement, but you might want to add extra security in the form of middleware.

Answer (score 0):

spatie permissions is a wonderful package that I use to make permissions to resources available to super-administrators. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission